# Function that generates a path along other path, from a starting to an end point

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, path-finding

```
const coords = [
  {
    name: "Rijnstraat vervolg",
    points: [
      [695, 500],
      [680, 480],
      [580, 475],
      [520, 460],
    ],
    width: 10,
    types: [types.car, types.truck, types.pedestrian, types.bike],
    oneway: true,
  },
 ...
]
```

[image: Example of what I already have]

I have an array that looks like the above and I want to make a function that generates a path (along the other paths, which are the black lines in the image) from a black or gray circle to another black or gray circle. So I want the function to take in a start and end point (black or gray circle) and return an array of points that follow the already existings paths. (Which are sort of like roads)
And the function can be described as someone who is trying to get to somewhere.

I already tried a recursive function that looks like this:

```
function calculatePathToShop(startPoint, shopPoint) {
  const targetShopPoint = findClosestPointOnPath(shopPoint);
  const targetPathIndex = findPathByPoint(targetShopPoint);
  const connectedPaths = calculateConnectedPaths(targetPathIndex);

  let startPathIndex = -1;
  connectedPaths.forEach(path => {
    const pathPoints = coords[path].points;
    pathPoints.forEach(pathPoint => {
      if (comparePoints(startPoint.point, pathPoint)) startPathIndex = path;
    });
  });

  if (startPathIndex == -1) return false;
  let startPathPoints = coords[startPathIndex].points;
  let targetPathPoints = coords[targetPathIndex].points;

  if (!comparePoints(startPoint.point, startPathPoints[0])) startPathPoints.reverse();

  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, .05)";
}
```

This one generated a path (along the existing ones) to a shop point, which is almost the same as a gray point. But this worked for some starting points, but the rest would just straight up fail

So does anyone know an algorithm, or has a function/solution that I can use to generate the path that someone can walk along the road (the black lines in the image)

Full coords array, and part of my already existing code is found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CodeFoxDev/people-simulation/main/func/paths.js

(The rest of the code is in the github repo itself)

Comment: What is a path for you? Some might say an array of points already is one.

Comment: I would like it to be an array of points to follow, in my opinion that would make the most sense.

Comment: What is it to be used for? As said above, You already have an Array of points, and that can already be considered a path. If you want to trace this path, you can already perform lineTo operations over these and adding more points in between won't help much. On the other hand, if you want to fill every pixels manually e.g by drawing rectangles, or by manipulating an ImageData, then that's a completely different task and you'll need to define a lot more. Like should there be antialiasing?,  how are the line-joints and miter joints to be rendered?, etc.

Comment: @kaiido I'm sorry if it wasn't clear enough in the beginning, so I update my question with a better explanation of my problem. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: So you actually want a [path-finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding)?

Comment: That is kind of what I want, but It's a quite specific and I couldn't find just what I was looking for. But it is indeed a pathfinder.

Comment: What in your dataset tells that there is a connection between two points A and B but not between A and C?

Comment: A path (or road) is defined in the coords array, with an object. The object has an array called points, those are all the points with which the path is connected, I my code there is also an array called intersections, those are calculated with a function, an intersection is where two or more points of paths overlap with each other.
To check if 2 paths collide, you can call the function "findCommonPoints" with 2 paths in them, it returns the collision point when found, or an empty array if not found.
[Github repository](https://github.com/CodeFoxDev/people-simulation)

Comment: Also make sure when calling any of the existing functions, to check if you need to use the path itself, the index, because I used both of them in different function (I will change that in the future).

Comment: What you need is not just to check if two paths cross each other, you need to know at which point they do. The best in your situation is to restructure your dataset into nodes where each node will hold a reference to all its neighbor nodes. Then the next step would be to walk that graph of nodes until you find the connection between your 2 targets, while avoiding infinite loops. Finally you'll have to measure the found paths length (by measuring the distance between each nodes in the path) and you're basically done. But this really has nothing to do with canvas, it's really just graph theory.

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed step interpolation

To interpolate a line segment you divide the vector from the start pointing to the end by the number of steps.

EG

```
steps = 100;
start = {x: 50, y: 100}
end = {x: 150, y: 300}
step = {x: (end.x - start.x) / steps, y: (end.y - start.y) / steps};
```

Then loop that number of steps adding the vector to a position initialized to the start point.

```
points = [];            // array of interpolated points
point = {...start}      // set start position.
while (steps--) {
    points.push({...point});
    point.x += vec.x;
    point.y += vec.y;
}
points.push({...end});  // last point at end
```

This will create different spacing for different line lengths.

### Fixed distance interpolation

To get a constant spacing between points you will need to use the lines' length to get the number of steps.

```
pixelsPerStep = 2;       // distance between points.
start = {x: 50, y: 100}
end = {x: 150, y: 300}

step = {x: end.x - start.x, y: end.y - start.y};
lineSteps = Math.hypot(step.x, step.y) / pixelsPerStep;
points = [];            // array of interpolated points

for (i = 0; i < lineSteps ; i += 1) {
    u = i / lineSteps;
    points.push({x: start.x + step.x * u, y: start.y + step.y * u});
}
// check to add end point
```

**Note** that the last point may or may not be at the correct distance. Due to rounding errors in floating point numbers you will need to check if the last point is close to the correct spacing and whether or not to include it.

eg from code above

```
// add last point if within (0.01 * pixelsPerStep) pixels of correct spacing
if (Math.abs(lineSteps - i) < 0.01) {
    points.push({...end});
}
```

**Note** Use the overflow `lineSteps - i` when interpolating many line segments, to carry the correct start offset to each subsequent line segment.

### Example

The code below is an example of a constant spaced set of points interpolated from another set of points.

The example draws the new points in black dots. The original points are rendered in red.

**Note** that the distance between new points is constant and thus may not fall on the original (red) points.

**Note** that there is a check at the end to test if a last point should be added.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const P2 = (x, y) => ({x, y});
const points = [
    P2(100,90),
    P2(300,210),
    P2(350,110),
    P2(50,10),
    P2(6,219),
];

const interpolatedPoints = interpolatePath(points, 35);
drawPoints(interpolatedPoints, 2);
ctx.fillStyle = "RED";
drawPoints(points);

function drawPoints(points, size = 1) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (const p of points) {
        ctx.rect(p.x - size, p.y - size, size * 2 + 1, size * 2 + 1);
    }
    ctx.fill();
}


function interpolatePath(path, pixelStep) {
    const res = [];
    var p2, i = 1, overflow = 0;
    while (i < path.length) {
        const p1 = path[i - 1];
        p2 = path[i];
        const dx = p2.x - p1.x;
        const dy = p2.y - p1.y;
        const len = Math.hypot(dx, dy) / pixelStep;
        let j = overflow;
        while (j < len) {
            const u = j / len;
            res.push(P2(p1.x + dx * u, p1.y + dy * u));
            j++;
        }
        overflow = j - len;
        i++;
    }
    
    // add last point if close to correct distance
    if (Math.abs(overflow) < 0.01) {
        res.push(P2(p2.x, p2.y));
    }
    return res;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but I wasn't what I meant.I updated the question to be more specific. Sorry for the inconvenience.